# Differntiability of a function $ F:\mathbb{R}^{n+n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This may sound very trivial but Im very confused.

Let $ f\left(\overrightarrow{x}\right):\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $ be a function such that   $ f\in C^{\left(1\right)}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n};\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) $ (differentiable and the partial derivatives are all continuous)

and define a function $ F\left(\overrightarrow{x},\overrightarrow{y}\right):\mathbb{R}^{n+n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n} $  by:

$ F\left(\overrightarrow{x},\overrightarrow{y}\right)=f\left(\overrightarrow{x}\right)-\overrightarrow{y} $

Why is it true that $ F\in C^{(1)}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n+n},\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) $ ?

my first intuition was to use the fact that the sum of two differntiable function is a differntiable function, but in this theorem the sum of the functions has to be a function from the mutual domain and here it is actually a "congrefate" of the domains so im it really confuses me.

Also I tried to think about it as composition of differntiable functions but also its not exactly a composition

If someone can help me understand how to think about it would be great, because the multivariable confuses me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The product of differentiable functions is differentiable: consider $(x,y)\rightarrow (f(x),y)$ which is the product of the identity and $f$ composed with $(x,y)\rightarrow x-y$.

Comment: Im sorry how $ (x,y)\to (f(x),y) $ is a product of the identity and $ f $ ?

Comment: Let $h_i:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, the product of $h_1$ and $h_2$ is defined by $h(x,y)=(h_1(x),h_2(x))$. Set $h_1=f$ and $h_2=Id_{{\mathbb R}^n}$.

Comment: And why does the product of differentiable functions is differntiable ? Can you point me to a proof ?